# Error importando módulo y declarando las variables

Tags: java, jdbc

Me salen los errores que se muestran en la imagen de abajo a pesar de todas las importaciones que hice y verifique.

[image: Captura de IDE utilizado]

Código:

```
...
String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sistemadeventas";
String usuario = "root";
String contraseña = "";

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, usuario, contraseña);
if (con != null)
    System.out.println("Se ha establecido una conexión a la base de datos " +
        "\n " + url);

stmt = (Statement) con.createStatement();
stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('" + 0 + "','" + cadena2 + "','" + cadena3 + "','" + cadena4 + "','" + cadena5 + "','" + cadena6 + "','" + cadena7 + "')");
System.out.println("Los valores han sido agregados a la base de datos ");
...
```

Comment: Ese no parece Javascript

Comment: Saludos Javier, bienvenido a SOes, te invito a dar una vuelta por https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour para que veas el funcionamiento del sitio y de paso obtienes tu primera medalla. Sería de muchísima utilidad para ti que edites tu pregunta agregando los errores que te salen, de tal manera la comunidad puede darte una mano con el tema.

Comment: @ftorres si ya cambiamos la etiqueta para que sea java jaja

Comment: Hay algo que no entiendo en tu INSERT. ¿Por qué pones CERO como si fuera una variable/constante? prueba a cambiar tu línea por esta `stmt.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO usuario VALUES('0','" + cadena2 + "','" + cadena3 + "','" + cadena4 + "','" + cadena5 + "','" + cadena6 + "','" + cadena7 + "')");`

Comment: Hola. ¿Podrías añadir las imports?
¿Declaras *stmt* como `Statement stmt` o `Statement stmt=null;` previamente al bloque try-catch?